# Aptana Studio 3 freezing on closing

Tags: macos, aptana

Often Aptana Studio 3 freezing after closing, and this process can be deleted only by manual closing app.

Answer (score 0):

Aptana is a pretty beastly app. I wouldn't be surprised if your machine was slow and it just takes a while to shut down.

Comment: Maybe, but i had two times, when i came home from work and Aptana was still running, and no response. There is mention, that this is from all-time-running terminal window in Aptana, I'm checkin it.